# How to validate each word separately in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, format

This should be easy, but it isn't, for me at least :(

I have a validation like this:

```
validates :l_name, format: { with: /\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b/ }
```

And my goal is to validate each word of given string. So if I set my l_name: "Cow Milk" it should pass, but when I pass: "cow Milk" or "Cow milk" I want it to return error. But for now validation pass as long as there is at least one capitalized word.

In regex console it looks good though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^([A-Z][a-z]*)+( [A-Z][a-z]*)*$`

**Explanation**

The first part `^([A-Z][a-z]*)` makes sure that the string starts `^` with a capitalized word `[A-Z]`, where a word could be also a single capitalized character, as `[a-z]*` means 0 or more of a to z.

The second part `( [A-Z][a-z]*)*$` checks for other capitalized words separated by spaces `( [`. But these words are optional indicated by `)*` meaning 0 or more of such words. The `$` makes sure that all words until the end of the string are capitalized. For instance without `$` this would also match `Cow milk in my coffee`.

Finally the `+` isn't necessary as it indicates 1 or more, but as we can only have one capitalized word at the start of a string we don't need it. So this 
will also work `^([A-Z][a-z]*)( [A-Z][a-z]*)*$`.

Comment: I had to change it to \A([A-Z][a-z]*)+( [A-Z][a-z]*)*\z but it the regex works great thnx :) I will upwoted if you provide explanation :)